# Add php odbc extension on Mac OS with unixODBC

Tags: php, unixodbc

I compiled the odbc extension for PHP with unixODBC on my mac. But on phpinfo, it shows like below:
[image]

Which should be:
[image]

Does anyone can help with it?

PHP version: 7.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the root cause. Need environment vars to make it run.